# Is it necessary to observe the pattern formed by two slits if comparable width to wavelength that rayliegh criteria needs to be satisfied?

Tags: optics, waves, double-slit-experiment

I know the intentsity pattern formed at the screen due to the interference and diffraction bith effects taking place in this above case but to clearly see the oattern is it necessary that raylieght criteria be satisfied , if not satsifed what will happen? reasoning needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is not.  The RC is for 2 independent light sources not a single source like in the DSE.  The RC refers to 2 overlapping single slit patterns .... the 2 patterns are caused by separated sources however they are being observed thru the same aperture.  When we observe the DSE pattern yes it could be a problem if we were to look thru a small aperture but that's not the case.

Comment: Sir i mentioned one condition that width of slits is comparable to wavelength so diffraction and interference both effects takes place :)

Comment: We are looking from other side of the screen isnt Sir ? Or from where we see the screen ?

Comment: it is tricky because in DSE we have a single correlated source .... and this is not a condition for Raleigh.

Comment: So we can observe accurately all the intensities in the setup without caring for RC? And from where do we observe the pattern from the back of the screen or something else Sir ?

Comment: In the DSE you can observe many ways.  Front view of screen, rear view of thin screen, camera, film .... with photons it is very easy.  For electrons it requires a complex apparatus.  Also people use a water wave tank .... but it is basic/simple interference .... not quantum/optical interference.